# How to separate text images from images that has both text and some figures

Tags: opencv, machine-learning

I am new to OpenCv and I have a problem where I need to separate text only images from images that has text along with some other figure element.

I am using EAST text detection for the same.
[image: text only image] - 
[image: image with both text and figure element].

East text detection is good but it doesn't work well with all the text images and the bounding box regions is also not accurate.

When i applied EAST text detection on this image:
[image: this image] 
the bounding box i get doesn't cover full text region shown in this image:
[image: shown in this image].

Is there any better way to do this?
Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If I am right, [this](http://cvisiondemy.com/extract-roi-from-image-with-python-and-opencv/) should answer your question.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but i am looking for an efficient way to extract text and non-text parts from an image. This will return a list of boxes but there is no efficient way to detect either the content inside that box is  all text or not. Since i have images with different font types, no OCR seems to work fine for my use case.